# no animation with jquery slide up/down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide a navigation element when the top of the `#preFooter` is reached.

I've developed the nav element to be mobile responsive so have created both `.tab-wrap` and `.tab-wrap-mobile`.

To allow both these items to slide away when I've reached the top of the `#preFooter` I've wrapped them in `.tab-wrap-all`.

However jQuery's `slideUp(); / slideDown();` methods aren't working as smoothly as they should.

I have a hunch it is do with how I've set up my `display` configurations in the css in order to hide the elements using media queries. But I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the Fiddle so far: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/0x68f545/

Comment: `z-index: 100000` Grrrr. Never ever do that.

Comment: what do you suggest @klenium? I'm using a v. rigid squarespace template, it was a quick fix.

Comment: Normally, setting `z-index` higher than 1-5 is not reasonable, it has no effect, because you don't have more than a few layers. You might want to read more about how `z-index` works. (It was just a note, it won't solve your actual problem)

Comment: Your fiddle is working for me with smooth toggle slide.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a longer duration to your slideUp() and slideDown() functions (default is 400)

Comment: That won't help. The problem is not that it's too fast, there is no any animation at all.

Comment: if you target only `.tab-wrap` you can see it works, but only on desktop. I need `.tab-wrap-mobile` to slide away too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the `position: fixed` on the child `.tab-wrap` element.

This is preventing the slideDown / slideUp from working, as the element you're attempting to animate isn't visually containing the fixed element inside it - fixed elements are positioned relative to the document, not any other containing element. When jQuery tries to animate the height of `.tab-wrap-all`, it has no height, so there's nothing to animate. The fixed element inside is only affected by the `display: none` that happens at the end of the animation.

If you apply this fixed positioning to the `.tab-wrap-all` element that you're animating instead, it will work fine.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/trijammer/0x68f545/3/